# How to convert binary Postgres data to text with Polars?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-polars

I am extracting data from POstgres with Polars.

The table looks like this:

```
 |     Column     |           Type           | 
 |----------------+--------------------------+
 | seq_id         | bigint                   |
 | id             | uuid                     |
 | version        | integer                  |
 | data           | jsonb                    |
 | timestamp      | timestamp with time zone |
```

The problem is when I execute a "SELECT * FROM table;" query I get id and data as binary in Polars.

The fix is to execute:

```sql
SELECT id::text, data::text, ... FROM table;
```

The problem with this is that I need to care about the fields in the table and I would like to have a job that does not have the list of fields spelled out.

Is there a way to instruct Polars to convert binary to text automatically?

I use the ADBC connector and the read_database_uri from Python:

```py
database_query = "SELECT id::text, data::text, ... FROM table;"
return pl.read_database_uri(
  query=database_query, uri=database_uri, engine="adbc"
)
```

Is there an easy way not needing to spell out fields and ::text for each binary column?

Comment: The challenge with binary data types, especially UUID and JSONB in PostgreSQL, is that they are not automatically interpreted as text by most database drivers and connectors, including ADBC, without explicit casting in the query. This is because these types have their specific binary representations that are not straightforwardly mapped to text without the explicit intent of doing so.  The resolution would be  explicitly casting each binary column to text in your query:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your setup so I can't test this but I'd think you could just do

#### Option 1

```
df=pl.read_database_uri(...).with_columns(
    pl.col(pl.Binary).cast(pl.String) 
)
```

#### Option 2

```
table_name = "dbtable"
df = pl.read_database_uri(f"select * limit 1 from {table_name}", ...)
col_str = ", ".join([x if y !=pl.Binary else f"{x}::text" for x,y in df.schema.items()])
df = pl.read_database_uri(f"select {col_str} from {table_name} ")
```

Comment: ```.with_columns(
... pl.col(pl.Binary).cast(pl.String)
... )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/i/...frame/frame.py", line 8290, in with_columns
    return self.lazy().with_columns(*exprs, **named_exprs).collect(_eager=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/lazyframe/frame.py", line 1937, in collect
    return wrap_df(ldf.collect())
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
polars.exceptions.ComputeError: invalid utf8```